# Admin controller is not being called in Magento Ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

I am calling admin controller via ajax, but it is not being called.
Here is the controller file-

**Assel/Allstock/controllers/Adminhtml/AllstockController**

```
<?php 
class Assel_Allstock_Adminhtml_AllstockController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  protected function _isAllowed()
  {
    return true;
  } 

  protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('Purchase')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Allstock'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Allstock'));

        return $this;
  }

  public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
             ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('allstock/adminhtml_allstock'))
            ->renderLayout();
  }

  public function productStockAction()
  {
      return "hello";
  }

  // Used for AJAX loading
   public function gridAction()
   {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('allstock/adminhtml_allstock_grid')->toHtml()
        );
   }
}
?>
```

Here is my **config.xml**-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
        <Assel_Allstock>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Assel_Allstock>
   </modules>
   <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <assel_allstock after="Mage_Adminhtml">Assel_Allstock_Adminhtml</assel_allstock>
                    </modules>
                </args>
           </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
   <global>
      <helpers>
            <allstock>
                <class>Assel_Allstock_Helper</class>
            </allstock>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <allstock>
                <class>Assel_Allstock_Block</class>
            </allstock> 
        </blocks>
   </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <assel_allstock>
                    <file>assel/allstock.xml</file>
                </allstock>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Here is the template file --

**adminhtml/base/default/template/assel/allstock.phtml**

```
 <script>
        var url= "<?php echo $this->getUrl('allstock/adminhtml_allstock/productStock/'); ?>";
        $j('#product_search').keyup(function() {
          delay(function(){
            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                  method: 'get',
                  onSuccess: function(response){debugger 
                  },
                  onFailure:  function(response) {debugger
                    Element.hide('loading-mask'); 
                    alert("An error has been occured during Ajax call, please try again");
                  },
            });
          }, 2000 );
        });
        var delay = (function(){
          var timer = 0;
          return function(callback, ms){
          clearTimeout (timer);
          timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
         };
        })();
    </script>
```

I am getting this value in url variable in ajax-

**"http://example.com/index.php/admin/allstock/productStock/key/NuEkv9QcEXoP4NWr/?isAjax=true"**

I am getting 404 error in ajax call. Not sure why I am getting this. Can anyone help me into this.

Comment: Which magento version are you using?

Comment: Using magento v1.9

Comment: Please tell full version?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MAgento 1.9.2.2 you are no longer allowed to implement your own admin routes, but instead have to use  and extend the used Controller list, like this:

> app/code/community/Pulsestorm/Adminhello/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Pulsestorm_Adminhello after="Mage_Adminhtml">Pulsestorm_Adminhello</Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

[Source: Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited)

Comment: @Febian, I have tried what you have suggested above but still my page shows 404 not found page on URL "http://example.com/index.php/admin/allstock/index/product_id/1829/key/fdd5a2e1980168f7cf4bc491b64d7c20/"

Comment: Login/Logout, ACL is loaded on login

Comment: I have cleared out all CACHE and did logout then login but no effect still getting 404 error page.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the new config.xml?

Comment: yes I have edited my config.xml, please check

Comment: I assume your controller file ends in `.php`? Then I think it is time to debug: Is the controller file called, is the init action called, what is the action, make sure the key check in `\Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::preDispatch` doesn't fail.

Comment: If I call url "http://example.com/index.php/admin/allstock/productStock" then it shows me 404 error page. instead of displaying" hello".